# wrong result parsing string in objective-C using componentsSeparatedByString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to parse a string *fileString*:

```
"contact1;12312312;John\ncontact2;34243442;Bill\n"


NSArray* lines = [fileString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
```

In debugger array *lines* consists of **3 objects**. Why?

[lines count] must be 2, but **why does it equal 3**?

```
NSString* line1 = [lines objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* line2 = [lines objectAtIndex:1];
NSString* line3 = [lines objectAtIndex:2];
```

*line1* is "contact1;12312312;John".

*line2* is "contact2;34243442;Bill".

*line3* has type (_NSCFConstantString *) and doesn't show a value in debugger.

Later I am using this array as a data source for a tableView, so I need a correct array count.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The input string has two separators and so the resulting array has three entries

1. Before the first \n
2. Between the \n
3. After the last \n

In this case the third one is an empty string (NSString with length of 0)

From [NSString documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)

> Similarly, if the string begins or ends with the separator, the first or last substring, respectively, is empty.

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to adjust the array before you use it as a data source, there are a couple of simple ways to clean your data, for instance:

```
NSString *csvString = @"Joe\nJane\nPaul\n";

// Cleaning by removing last newline
csvString = [csvString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\n$" withString:@"" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, csvString.length)];

NSArray *lines = [csvString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

// Cleaning by removing all empty lines
lines = [lines filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"length > 0"]];
```

You would of course only need one of these cleaning operations, and they can both be tweaked to suit your specific input data.

Comment: Thanks! It's better than making [lines count] - 1 :-) I'll use your code.